# How to declare protocol in separate header file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have two classes. Both these classes are delegates of each other. This gives me error like "Can not find protocol declaration". After searching on net, I came to the conclusion that, this is the case of cyclic dependency.

To break this dependency the solution they have suggested is to define protocol in another header file. I could not find any tutorial on how to do this and how will it affect my code?

Comment: can u display the code which you have written to make delegates for each other,so that i can edit your code according to your requirement

Comment: usually we write as @class b rather than #import class b...

Comment: Kindly Display what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [@Toro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419348/toro)'s answer in this previous SO question 
[UIViewController calling each other's delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086514/uiviewcontroller-calling-each-others-delegate)

Answer (score 2):

I have a example for you..

```
@class ClassA;
@class ClassAController;

@protocol CreateClassADelegate
-(void)CreateClassA:(ClassAController *)sender didCreateClassA:(ClassA *)ClassAObj;
-(void)CreateClassACancel:(TSInputController *)sender;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `XCode 4` you just creating new file as always, the difference is that you need to choose `Objective-C protocol` in `Cocoa Touch` section rather then `Objective-C class` or `UIViewController subclass`. 
Other approach you may use is to create new `Objective-C class` and then just delete the .m file manualy and change `@interface` to `@protocol` in .h file.