# Two delegates which define the same function?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, dry

I have two classes - CompletionView and PauseView - each of which has an associated delegate. I already have a function, returnHome, in the CompletionDelegate and I need the same functionality in my PauseView delegate. My question is, do I have to write two functions with duplicate functionality? Or can one function satisfy two protocols? i.e., can both CompletionDelegate and PauseDelegate require that returnHome be defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just define your protocol in an external header, import that into both CompletionView and PauseView, and create delegates based on that external protocol.

Protocols don't necessarily need to be tied directly to views.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086514/uiviewcontroller-calling-each-others-delegate), but you likely don't even need to define @class and all that if your delegate method doesn't specifically need those classes. You should be able to just define `returnHome` under something like `GeneralUseDelegate`  and define/use that delegate in both views.

```
@protocol GeneralUseDelegate

- (void) returnHome;

@end
```

Didn't test, but can't imagine why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah I selected this one instead, if you read my comment, this is what I did. I made a ModalDelegate and made the class-specific functions optional.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a common superClass for CompletionView and PauseView and define the protocol and place the delegate property there

Comment: I'm doing something similar. I'm creating a ModalDelegate and then both of them will import it.